# How does hadoop distribute jobs to map and reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can anyone explain me how hadoop decides to pass the jobs to map and reduce. Hadoop jobs are passed onto map and reduce but I am not able to figure out the way in which its done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer Hadoop Definitive guid, Chapter 6, Anatomy of a MapReduce Job Run topic. Happy Learning

Answer (score 0):

From Apache [mapreduce tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) :

**Job Configuration:**

`Job` represents a MapReduce job configuration.

`Job` is the primary interface for a user to describe a `MapReduce` job to the Hadoop framework for execution. The framework tries to faithfully execute the job as described by Job

**Task Execution & Environmen**

The `MRAppMaster` executes the `Mapper/Reducer` task as a child process in a separate jvm.

**Mapper**

`Mapper` maps input key/value pairs to a set of intermediate key/value pairs.

**How Many Maps?**

The number of maps is usually driven by the total size of the inputs, that is, `the total number of blocks of the input files`.

**Reducer**

Reducer reduces a set of intermediate values which share a key to a smaller set of values.

The number of reduces for the job is set by the user via `Job.setNumReduceTasks(int).`

**How Many Reduces?**

`The right number of reduces seems to be 0.95 or 1.75 multiplied by (<no. of nodes> * <no. of maximum containers per node`>).

**Job Submission and Monitoring**

The job submission process involves:

1. Checking the input and output specifications of the job.
2. Computing the InputSplit values for the job.
3. Setting up the requisite accounting information for the DistributedCache of the job, if necessary.
4. Copying the job’s jar and configuration to the MapReduce system directory on the FileSystem.
5. Submitting the job to the ResourceManager and optionally monitoring it’s status.

**Job Input**

InputFormat describes the input-specification for a MapReduce job. InputSplit represents the data to be processed by an individual Mapper.

**Job Output**

OutputFormat describes the output-specification for a MapReduce job.

Go through that tutorial for further understanding of complete workflow.

From [AnatomyMapReduceJob](http://ercoppa.github.io/HadoopInternals/AnatomyMapReduceJob.html) article from http://ercoppa.github.io/ :
The workflow can be pictured as below.

[image: Hadoop Map Reduce Job Internals]